# How to read dbg binary output in file?

Tags: erlang

I traced with dbg my system. I used

```
dbg:trace_port(file,{"/tmp/trace",wrap,atom_to_list(node()),10000000,20})
```

now I have couple binary files.

Never really used those binary dumps.. How to read them?
rb? disk_log? How to start up them to see log file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not tried this myself, but [`dbg:trace_client/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html#trace_client-2) looks like it can read the file.

Answer (score 6):

First you use trace_port to get a PortFun like so :

`1> PortFun = dbg:trace_port(file,{"/tmp/trace",wrap,atom_to_list(node()),10000000,20}).`

Then use dbg:tracer to start a tracer that will route the messages :

`2> dbg:tracer(port, PortFun).`

The output of the trace can be received using trace_client :

```
1> Pid = dbg:trace_client(file,FileName).
..
dbg output here...
..
2> dbg:stop_trace_client(Pid).
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, you could also try [et_viewer:file/1](http://erlang.org/doc/man/et_viewer.html#file-1), which will show the trace in a window where you can examine, eg individual calls, one by one.

*Note: The vertical scroll in that window did not work properly on my system so I just copied the text and examined it in an editor.*